# java - a weird counter - invalid disconnected digits

Tags: java, algorithm, counting

I would like to know if there is any way to count like this:

**base of each position:**

```
4 2 3
```

**counter values:**

```
000--invalid - exception, always a non zero digit must be there
001
002
010
011
012
100
101--invalid : disconnected digits
102--invalid : disconnected digits
110
111
112
200
201--invalid : disconnected digits
202--invalid : disconnected digits
210
211
212
300
301--invalid : disconnected digits
302--invalid : disconnected digits
310
311
312
```

The idea is if non-zero digits are separated by zero, then leave that formation out. That means values like 101, 201 are invalid.

talking about decimal counting system for example (max: 9999), numbers like 1001, or 9010 will not be produced.

I came up with counting and then converting to each base, (in my first example, the bases would be 4.2.3 and for the 9999 example it would be 10.10.10.10) however, there are certain numbers of all numbers that they will be valid.

for example:

```
4.2.3: 17 out of 4*2*3 (or 24) will be valid
4.2.2.4: 30 out of 4*2*2*4 (or 64) will be valid
10.10.10.10: 8298 out of 10*10*10*10 (or 10000) will be valid.
```

as positions goes up, the more computation I need to perform.

What is your idea about a fast counter that can produce such numbers?

a simple solution as I mentioned would be count and convert, and then do a post process on generated numbers, but what is the optimized solution for this?

here is my code:

```
/**
 * Author: Soleyman Pasban
 * Date: Apr 6, 2016 
 */
package PC;

public class DigitTest {

    public static void main(String[] test) {
        //int[] base = new int[]{4, 2, 3};
        int[] base = new int[]{4, 2, 2, 4};
        //int[] base = new int[]{10,10,10,10};

        int valid = 0;
        int total = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
            total *= base[i];
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < total; i++) {

            int number = i;
            int bi = base.length - 1;
            String str = "";
            while (bi >= 0) {
                str = number % base[bi] + str;
                number = number / base[bi];
                bi--;
            }

            boolean pass = true;
            boolean allowNonZero = true;

            for (int j = 1; j < base.length; j++) {
                if (str.charAt(j - 1) == '0' && str.charAt(j) != '0') {
                    //for the first case ...0* it should filter the cases
                    //I bypass it once by this, else the number must mark invalid
                    if (allowNonZero == false) {
                        pass = false;
                    }
                    allowNonZero = false;
                }
                //once see a zero, no none-zero must be appear
                if (str.charAt(j - 1) != '0') {
                    allowNonZero = false;
                }
            }

            if (pass) {
                valid++;
            } else {
                str += " - invalid";
            }

            System.out.println(str);

        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Valid: " + valid);
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
}
```

My question is if there is a way to keep the above algorithm simple. for a 16 digits like 4.8.7.2.2.3.2.2.4.2.7.4.2.3.2.2 (this is an example to show that it must work with any base) the amount of calculation, creating string variables and other stuff I think will be inefficient!

for an example if a number start with like 9010*********1 then this number is wrong from the beginning and counting the rest will be meaningless.

Is there any other solution for this problem? I would like to see if I can just produce the valid numbers by this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually fairly simple. You start by creating a `char[]` of `'0'` characters for the appropriate length.

You then increment the last digit, and rollover when necessary. The updated array is then the next value, and you create the result using `new String(buf)`.

Now, the trick is that when you roll over, you set the digit back to `0`, and move one position to the left, and increment that. But, you remember how far you had to go left during chained rollovers, because you must increment the left-most zero on the next iteration, in order to prevent "disconnected digits".

Example:

```
1999
2000  <-- rollover, remember that second digit must be incremented next
2100  <-- now remember that third digit must be incremented next
2110  <-- now remember that forth digit must be incremented next
2111  <-- normal increment
2112  <-- normal increment
```

Since a weird counter like this is best if reusable, here is a class implementing this logic, including validation:

```
public final class WeirdCounter {
    private int[]  bases;
    private char[] buf;
    private int    idx;
    public WeirdCounter(int ... bases) {
        if (bases.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No bases");
        for (int base : bases)
            if (base < 1 || base > 10)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid base:" + base);
        this.bases = bases.clone();
        this.buf = new char[bases.length];
        Arrays.fill(this.buf, '0');
        this.idx = this.buf.length - 1;
    }
    public String next() {
        while (this.idx >= 0) {
            char digit = this.buf[this.idx];
            if (++digit < '0' + this.bases[this.idx]) {
                this.buf[this.idx] = digit;
                if (this.idx < this.buf.length - 1)
                    this.idx++;
                return new String(this.buf);
            }
            this.buf[this.idx--] = '0';
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is very fast and easy to use:

```
WeirdCounter counter = new WeirdCounter(4,2,3);
for (String val; (val = counter.next()) != null; )
    System.out.println(val);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
001
002
010
011
012
100
110
111
112
200
210
211
212
300
310
311
312
```

Note that the 16-digit example you gave (`4.8.7.2.1.3...4.6.7.9.10...3.1.1`) makes no sense. What does `...` mean? Also, a base of `1` means that the digit can only ever be `0`.

So, assuming that `.` means `1`, the code will work. When a rollover crosses any such base-1 value, all digit to the right *must* stay `0`.

Partial output using `new WeirdCounter(4,8,7,2,1,3,1,4,6,7,9,10,1,3,1,1)`:

```
...
0000000356870000
0000000356880000
0000000356890000
0000010000000000
0000020000000000
0001000000000000
0010000000000000
0011000000000000
0020000000000000
0021000000000000
0030000000000000
0031000000000000
0040000000000000
0041000000000000
0050000000000000
0051000000000000
0060000000000000
0061000000000000
0100000000000000
0110000000000000
0111000000000000
...
```

Still, code is very, very fast, because when it tries to increment `0001000000000000`, it knows to increment the first zero after the `1`, so it immediate rolls over the base-1 digit and then increments the `1` digit to `2` instead, without even looking at the those other `0` digits.

Comment: Really algorithmic! Thank you very much. I choose this because of fairly nice idea, less complicated with not so many for's, and a class implementation!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Digits {
// make constructor or something
int[] base = new int[]{4, 2, 3};
int[] cur = new int[]{0, 0, 0};

public void find(int i, boolean hasNonZero) {
    if (i == base.length) {
        if (!hasNonZero) {
            return; // all zeroes corner case
        }
        // output
        for (int j = 0; j < base.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(cur[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    for (int v = 0; v < base[i]; v++) { // each digit at position
        if (hasNonZero && v != 0 && cur[i - 1] == 0) { // disconnected non zeroes
            continue;
        }
        cur[i] = v;
        find(i + 1, hasNonZero || v != 0); // next position
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    (new Digits()).find(0, false);
}
}
```

Simple recursion like this.

Comment: Nice recursive implementation. Different approach from [my iterative implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36438297/5221149), but it handles that 16-digit example very well too.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the count without generating any numbers. Here's a simple `O(n^3)` solution to demonstrate the idea. It can probably be improved further.

```
public class DigitTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    countWeirdNumbers(4, 2, 3);
    countWeirdNumbers(4, 2, 2, 4);
    countWeirdNumbers(10, 10, 10, 10);
  }

  public static void countWeirdNumbers(int... bases) {
    long count = 0;
    for (int start = 0; start < bases.length; start++) {
      for (int end = start; end < bases.length; end++) {
        int thisCount = 1;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          thisCount *= bases[i] - 1;
        }
        count += thisCount;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

The idea is that you're simply counting how many numbers don't have any zeroes in between the first and last nonzero digits. So iterate over all the possible positions of those two digits and count the possibilities for the digits in that range. Each digit has `b-1` possibilities where `b` is the base at that position because `0` isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-fast way that doesn't generate any invalid numbers.  Just change the initializers for `maxdigits` and `current` for different base sequences.

It works by directly incrementing the previous number, so you can make an iterator out of it if you like.

This is good pattern to remember for generating a wide variety of different kinds of sequences in lexical order:

Given the "current item", you can always make the next item with these 2 steps:

1. Increment the rightmost character that can be greater than the corresponding character in the current item.  This works because the next item must be greater, and given that must share the longest possible prefix in common with the current item.  Then
2. Set the remaining characters to the lowest possible value, because otherwise you'd be skipping some.

These steps make it pretty easy to generate your sequence, and indeed a whole lot of other lexically ordered sequences.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    char[] maxdigits = "312".toCharArray();
    char[] current = "001".toCharArray();
    for (;;)
    {
        System.out.println(new String(current));

        //each time we add 1, one digit is incremented by one,
        //and all the lower-place digits are set to the least possible
        //value

        //Step 1 - find the position of digit to increment
        boolean sawNonZero=false;
        int incpos;
        for(incpos = current.length-1; incpos>=0; --incpos)
        {
            if (current[incpos]=='0')
            {
                if (sawNonZero || current[incpos-1]!='0')
                {
                    //can increment a leading zero or the first trailing zero
                    break;
                }
                //incrementing this one would create a zero gap
            }
            else
            {
                sawNonZero = true;
                if (current[incpos]<maxdigits[incpos])
                {
                    //can increment a digit that is less than max
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (incpos<0)
        {
            break; //done
        }
        current[incpos]++;

        //Step 2 - set the remaining digits to 0
        for (incpos+=1; incpos<current.length; ++incpos)
        {
            current[incpos]='0';
        }
    }
}
```